# React router dom v5 Nested routes never matching

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have two main pages: LoginPage and HomePage. HomePage is main page with navbar and content. I'm trying to implement nested routing.

- loginPage
- HomePage

  - SchoolsPage
  - UserDetails

I prepared routing for them:

```
<Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute
          key="loginPage"
          path={`${ROOT_PATHS.login}`}
          component={AuthPageContainer}
          shouldBeRedirected={authState === 'AUTHENTICATED'}
          authenticationPath={`${ROOT_PATHS.version}`}
        />
        <ProtectedRoute
          key="homePage"
          path={ROOT_PATHS.version}
          component={HomePageContainer}
          shouldBeRedirected={authState === 'NOT_AUTHENTICATED'}
          authenticationPath={`${ROOT_PATHS.login}`}
        />
      </Switch>
```

Home page:

```
export const HomePage: React.FC<HomePageProps> = ({ fetchUserInfo, user, isLoading, userLogout }): JSX.Element => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserInfo()
  }, [fetchUserInfo])

  return (
    <LoadingContent isLoading={isLoading}>
      <Navbars user={user} userLogout={userLogout} />
      <Pages />
    </LoadingContent>
  )
}
```

An routings in Pages:

```
export const Pages: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const { url, path } = useRouteMatch()
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${url}${ROOT_PATHS.userDetails}`} exact component={UserDetailsContainer} />
      <Route path={`${url}${ROOT_PATHS.schools}`} exact component={SchoolListContainer} />
      <Route path={`${path}`} exact>
        {console.log('redirected')}
        <Redirect to={`${url}${ROOT_PATHS.schools}`} />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

And paths:

```
export const ROOT_PATHS = {
  login: '/login',
  version: '/v1',
  schools: '/schools',
  userDetails: '/userDetails'
}
```

My index.tsx:

```
// axios should be configured before saga because saga makes requests on startup
configureAxios()
const store = configureStore()

export const DOMStructure: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => (
  <Suspense fallback={<Spinner animation="border" role="status" />}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <CookiesProvider>
          <AppContainer />
        </CookiesProvider>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  </Suspense>
)

ReactDOM.render(<DOMStructure />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

It all works fine when navigating via links in navbar.
But when I refresh page, it never matches to any child-routes and is redirected to v1/schools (I checked that with console.log('redirected').

So I cannot render page under specific ur. When I put 'localhost:3000/v1/userDetails' in browser, it's always redirected to 'localhost:3000/v1/schools'.

Why is that? What i'm missing?